# Issue with the Microsoft Translation API in Expression 2 on GMOD Wire

Tags: api, azure, lua

I am using the api available on the azure marketplace, however when I try to use it in an E2 chip for Gmod 13, I get the following error...

```
The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported
```

Now, I have checked for a means of authenticating, but I cannot find one.

Here is my code... its remade from someone elses code that used the dictionary.com translator which broke.

```
@name Language Translator - By Moglizorz - Patched by Scorn (test 6)
@persist Lang:string
#Test 1: Attempted to adjust the old translation api to detect single word entries.
#Test 2: Attempted to add support for both 1 word and multi-word entries,
#Test 3: After the failures of test 1 and 2, I have attempted to move to the Google translate.
#Test 4: Google is unresponsive, I have found the bing translator api and am attempting to use it.
#Test 5: Correction on last test: Its the Microsoft translation api. Also, I am getting an error over and over regarding failed authorization. Attempting to change from https to http.
#Test 6: I have reverted Test 5 due to identical failure, and have removed some unnecessary code.
runOnChat(1)
runOnHTTP(1)
if(first()){Lang="en"}elseif(duped()){reset()}
if((chatClk(owner()))&(lastSaid():sub(1,6)=="!lang ")){
    hideChat(1)
    print("[Hidden] Set language to: "+lastSaid():sub(6))
    Lang=lastSaid():sub(7,lastSaid():length())
}elseif((lastSaid():sub(1,1)=="~")&(chatClk(owner()))){
    hideChat(1)
    print("[Hidden] Translating: "+lastSaid():sub(2))
    httpRequest("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text="+httpUrlEncode(lastSaid():sub(2,lastSaid():length()))+"&From=en&to="+Lang )
}
if((httpClk())&(httpRequestUrl():find("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=")>0)) {
    S=httpData()
    S=S:replace("&amp;","&"):replace("&quot;","\"")
    S=httpUrlDecode(S)
    concmd("say\""+S+"\"")
}
#To be added: Two way support. So that the person I am talking to will have their text translated to me locally.
```

You may notice some similarities to PHP and LUA... thats E2 for you.

If you wish to test it, you will need GMOD13, and must use wire_expression2_concmd 1 in the console beforehand.

You can also find any and all documentation for the E2 language at [Expression2](https://github.com/wiremod/wire/wiki/Expression-2) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229205931/http://wiki.garrysmod.com/?title=Wire_Expression2))

Comment: The error you are getting is from this [page](https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you see is from the following statement:

```
httpRequest("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text="+httpUrlEncode(lastSaid():sub(2,lastSaid():length()))+"&From=en&to="+Lang )
```

According to the [Microsoft Translator schema](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator#schema)

> This service **supports fixed query**. Some queries may include required
>   input parameters.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Now, the method on creating a fixed query is also covered by the help-docs in [this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg312154.aspx). As you'd notice in the [Step 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg312154.aspx#Step4) of the docs, you'll see that they have:

```
private const string USER_ID = "yourLiveId";
private const string SECURE_ACCOUNT_ID = "yourMarketplaceAccountKey";  // not your Live password
private const string ROOT_SERVICE_URL = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Alteryx/CensusDemographicData";
```

and later in the same code block

```
public CensusDemographicData()
{
    serviceUri = new Uri(ROOT_SERVICE_URL);
    context = new CensusDemographicDataContainer(serviceUri);
    context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USER_ID,
                                                SECURE_ACCOUNT_ID);
```

You are missing the `Credentials` arguments in your query; which isn't fixed at all.

Comment: Uh, I tried using this by just adding &Credentials=(myaccountkey) but it has the same errors. How can i simply add it to the httprequest?

Comment: @Scorn Take a look at [these pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx).